# Drawing a textured 3D object breaks SFML text render

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I writing a OpenGL game using SFML.

I'm using the push/pop function to combine OpenGL with SFML like the tutorial [SFML+OpenGL](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/window-opengl.php) but, when I added textures to my model, the SFML text rendering appears broken and wrong rendered.

The simplified loop I used is:

```
while( true ){
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glUseProgram( programID );

    // Draw the 3d textured object
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d0 );

    object.draw();

    window->pushGLStates();

    window->setView( view );
    window->draw( text );
    window->setView( window->getDefaultView() );

    window->popGLStates();

    window->display();
}
```

My 3d model is draw right but something in the glActiveTexture/glBindTexture mess up the text in the SFML part.

If I add:

```
glActiveTexture( 0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
```

And the end of my OpenGL rendering code, nothing is fixed anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFML but it can only saves/restores OpenGL 2.x states. We must disable what we enable in +3.x states. It works adding:

It's fixed adding at the end of own drawing something like:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
glUseProgram( 0 );
```